# Selecting entire tables based on wildcard name values SQL - Tableau

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

What I'm trying to do is to pull out a subset of tables from a Google Big Query Dataset based on the name of those tables and then add those tables to a Tableau datasource without having to join or union any of the tables.

I want to pull out all the tables beginning with System_1, from the below dataset

1. System_1_Start
2. System_1_Middle
3. System_1_End
4. System_2_Start
5. System_2_Middle
6. System_2_End
7. System_3_Start
8. System_3_Middle
9. System_3_End

I have been able to do a wildcard search using Information_Schema.Tables to get all the names of the tables that begin with System_1, but I cannot figure out a way to then get all of the tables with those names as the output of the query (SQL below)

```
SELECT table_name
AS matchingTables
FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name LIKE 'System_1%'
```

How do I go about extracting those tables and not just the names of those tables?

**~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

This is the best approximation as to how I could have done this but I'm getting a dataset not found error which is strange

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset
WHERE (SELECT table_name FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
LIKE 'System_1%'
```

Error Recieved:

Not found: Dataset dataset:dataset was not found in location EU

Comment: From what I can tell, you need to construct the query as string and execute the query -- you can't do this with a simple `select`.  The basic problem is that you are storing data in multiple tables that should all be in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the list of the table names in your dataset that start with "System_1_". You can obtain that with the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT("System_1_", _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS table_name
FROM `dataset.System_1_*`
```

Comment: Yes and no, I initially wanted to be able to pull any table with the Prefix of "System_1_" without joining or merging the tables as they will have different columns in them. 

Now, I've decided to just select any common columns from the tables with an added column with the above solution in there to identify from which table any given row comes from. Its less elegant as it means I can't treat each table as individually as I would have liked to but it does work for the general case.